# .Net core sdk on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've just installed .not Code sdk 2.1 on ubuntu 18.10 using snap
I've started new console project and try to run it with my vs code installation, but it can not compile. It seems that on snap .net core installation on ubuntu dotnet commands are prefixed by dotnet-sdk.
I give an example :

> dotnet-sdk.dotnet --version

What additionnal configuration should i set up in vs code in order to make it work with extensions, compiler and so ?

Comment: Do you have both SDK and Runtime installed? If so, that might be an issue to look into.

Comment: Snap support is considered experimental https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-net-core-2-1/ So such issues are expected. You might post to the developers, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues

Comment: thank u for help. I have both sdk and runtime installed. I'm gonna try desinstalling runtime.

Comment: I'll post to omnisharp developpers too on github

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have both SDK and Runtime installed. If so, that might be an issue to look into.